# How to restore the original MPC-BE user interface?

Tags: media-player-classic

I must have accidentally switched to an alternate UI, presumably with a hotkey. How can I restore the original interface without clearing configuration settings?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>3</kbd> to restore the default view.

[source](https://trac.mpc-hc.org/ticket/1496) (MPC-BE still functions identically to MPC-HC on this respect)